# ¿Por que se inserta mal la fecha en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, date

Tengo un código PHP para insertar nombre y fecha en mi base de datos.
Lo usaré para una App android, el problema está en que yo inserto los parámetros en el navegador para probar que todo funcione. Es decir: Nombre=nombre&Fecha=02/23/2019
El problema es que cuando voy a la DB el nombre se guarda bien pero la fecha se guarda así "0000-00-00"
Ya probé poniendo "-" en vez de "/", también poniendo año/mes/dia, año/dia/mes dia/mes/año, mes/dia/año

Mi codigo PHP es este:

```
<?php
$nombre = $_REQUEST["Nombre"];
$fecha = $_REQUEST["Fecha"];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id8622999_user", "Carlos78", "id8622999_dbprueba5" ) or die ("Sin conexión");
$sql = "insert into cita (nombre, fecha) values ('$nombre', $fecha)";
$resul = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo $resul;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que estructura tiene tu base de datos? Puede que sea eso lo que te esté causando conflictos.

Comment: Gracias por responder Luis Diaz. Realmente no se a que se refiere, ya que soy novato en este tema

Comment: Supongo que la columna `fecha` de la base de datos es del tipo `date` o `datetime`. El formato que asume esa columna es `YYYYMMDD` o esa, las 4 cifras del año, las dos cifras del mes, las dos cifras del día. Toda inserción que vayas a hacer conviene que se la pases así: `2019/02/23`, también son válidos: `20190223` o bien `2019-02-23`, lo importante es guardar el formato `YYYYMMDD`, de lo contrario interpretará que es `0000-00-00` y en algunos casos puede confundirse. Si no puedes formatear así al recoger los datos, debes hacerlo antes de insertarlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo ha sido válido el formato. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen Dia.- Asumiendo que el campo fecha es de tipo Date en la tabla cita. Lo primero que tienes que saber es que para este tipo de campos el formato valido es yyyy-mm-dd (Año, mes, dia y utilizando como separador el guion). Lo segundo es que pudieras tener un error en la sentencia SQL en relacion a las comillas. Intenta sustituir esa linea por esta:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cita (nombre, fecha) VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$fecha)."'";
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! Me lo has resuelto amigo. MUCHAS GRACIAS. solo he cambiado el ultimo parentesis $sql = "INSERT INTO cita (nombre, fecha) VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$fecha."')"; y ha quedado perfecto, de nuevo GRACIAS.

Answer (score 1):

en tu sentencia SQL rescatas la variable `fecha` como si fuera un numero (le falta las ')

```
$sql = "insert into cita (nombre, fecha) values ('$nombre', $fecha)";
```

**Solucion:**

```
$sql = "insert into cita (nombre, fecha) values ('$nombre', '$fecha')";
```